# How to customize Flash Message with inline css in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In my Controller :

```
$this->Flash->success(__(' Your Data has been Saved Successfully. Sheets Name in this XLS file : <span style="color:#FF9900"> '.$SheetName.'</span>'));
```

In my success.ctp located in Element\Falsh :

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in" onclick="this.classList.add('hidden')"> <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a> <strong>Success!</strong> <?= h($message) ?> </div>
```

The Message is display like :[image]

Now the question is how to use inline css in the flash message.

Comment: Just echo `$message` instead of `h($message)`? Should be safe, as long as `$SheetName` isn't coming directly from user input.

Comment: thanks @Greg Schmidt its working now

Answer (score 0):

I think the soloution for your problem would be to use another layout for this type of message.

```
$this->Flash->set($message, $options[])
```

You can specify to use a specific element in the options. Something like this:

create a new confirmation.ctp inyour project:

```
<div class="[...]">
    <?= h($message) ?>
    <span style="color:#FF9900">
        <?= h($params['sheetName']) ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

now when you want to show the new confirmation use this code:

```
$this->Flash->set(__('The Message:'), [
    'element' => 'confirmation, 
    'params' => [
        'sheetName' => $SheetName
    ]
]);
```

This will display your custom flash element.